# Javascript !function(){}?? What is it mean?

Tags: javascript, function

Last I meet

```
!function () {
   function a() {
      some code here . . .
   }    
} ();
```

I know that **"!"** similar "not" negative particle, Everything work fine in this function, but I want know why in this case are used this **"!"** ??

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

It's an immediately-invoked function expression. Instead of `(function(){})();` you can save a few bytes by using a unary operator: `!function(){}();`, `~function(){}();` etc...

An immediately-invoked function expression – IIFE for short – is as the name suggests a function that is immediately invoked. [Read more at Ben Alman](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)